# Exclipse JavaFX SceneBuilder GridPane

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, gridpane

i can't use GridPane in SceneBuilder (eclipse), when i try to insert GridPane in my project, the SceneBuilder quit without prompt any message.

and that's what i find in the log file:

## # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fed6a35c01, pid=2184, tid=3708 # # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27) # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) # Problematic frame: # C [MSVCR120.dll+0x95c01] # # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Comment: Could You please provide more information for us to be able to reproduce instead of just linking some random tutorial from the internet?

Comment: i can't simply use gridpane in scenebuilder. when i try to insert it in my project..scenebuilder quits suddenly without prompt any message.

Comment: and that's what i find in the log file:

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fed6a35c01, pid=2184, tid=3708
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [MSVCR120.dll+0x95c01]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Comment: could You please edit and fix the original question adding these details and specific steps You've did?

Comment: So you are making an fxml with SceneBuilder,all working well in SceneBuilder but when you add GridPane in fxml the you have this error?When this error happens , be specific ...

Comment: Yes that's it. when i add a GridPane in my fxml the scenebuilder quit suddanly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by installing SceneBuiled 32bit.